# finding duplicate field values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 0.19.4 (I know this is old, but its what is required by a dependency)

I have a field "digest" in an elasticsearch index - and I would like to execute a query that will return me all the cases where there are duplicate values of digest. Can this be done?

For the records that have duplicate values, I would like to return other values - such as "url" which may not be duplicated.

Comment: I am also looking for the same but till now did not find anything.
If anyone knows the answer of this question then please reply.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Terms Aggregation` for this.

```
POST <index>/<type>/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
       "duplicateNames": {
           "terms": {
               "field": "digest",
               "size": 0,
               "min_doc_count": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return all values of the field `digest` which occur in at least 2 documents. I agree this does not exactly match to your use case but it might help.